# Select Difference Between Rows (Postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql

i'm aggregating facebook "like" counts for urls over time. each hour, i check the "like" count and insert it into a timestamped row. how can i get the difference in total between the new row and the previous hour's row?

eg,

1. insert total=5 for id=1 at 2pm
2. insert total=12, diff_since_last=7 for id=1 at 3pm

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This should do it.

```
SELECT id, 
       total, 
       total - lag(total) over (partition by id order by timestamp_column) as diff_since_last
FROM the_table_with_no_name
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried a_horse_with_no_name's solution I had to remove the 'partition by id' portion to get a result (I'm using PG 9.2)

SELECT id, 
       total, 
       total - lag(total) over (order by timestamp_column) as diff_since_last
FROM the_table_with_no_name